# Crypto.js: "Uint8ClampedArray" is undefined in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cryptojs

`Crypto JS` uses `Uint8ClampedArray` which is not support by any version of `IE`. Are there any known workarounds?

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have similar error in IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963963/converting-a-hex-string-of-a-raw-image-to-a-bitmap-image-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue open in CryptoJS project page:

http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/issues/detail?id=81

Some workarounds are discussed there.

An solution might be to use more recent (unreleased) code of CryptoJS.

An issue on MS IE web pages regarding support for types arrays:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808589/html-canvas-does-not-return-imagedata-as-uint8clampedarray